# Building a Social Network on a database: Graph vs. Relational.... Or Both?

Tags: mongodb, rest, api, neo4j, social-networking

I am currently building the REST API backend for a social networking app that I am creating. The backend will be written in node js. I am trying to decide whether I should use a Graphing DB (Neo4J) or MongoDB. In Neo4J i will be able to query relationships a lot faster and will be able to provide recommendations and such much easier. However, MongoDB's document structure means I will have a lot more flexibility in storing data such as permissions, user's posts, etc. Would it be wise to build a MongoDB database with data, and then store references to the documents in a Neo4J database, allowing me to pull recommendations, but still providing the document flexibility???

Answer (score 0):

Since Neo4j is a schemaless DB (like MongoDB), it seems Neo4j satisfies all of your requirements.